# Read multiple lines from file using fgets() and store to array of pointers

Tags: c, bash, shell, pointers, fgets

I am trying to implement a custom shell on "batch-file mode". Let's say I have a file named "batchfile" containing:

```
ls –l
pwd
ps
touch hello
ls -l ; cat file ; grep foo file2
ls -l && cat file
quit
```

Calling `./myShell batchfile`, I want to execute the commands separately. But when I try to read the lines from the file using `fgets()` and then store them to an array (`char * batch_cmds[512]`) I get :

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is my code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc >=2){
        char str[512];
        char *batch_cmds[512];
        int i=0; 
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        while(fgets(str,512, fp)!=NULL){
            strcpy(batch_cmds[i], str);
            i++;
        }
    fclose(fp);
```

I can 't understand why this error pops.

Comment: you don't allocate any memory for `batch_cmds` so (for example) `batch_cmds[0]` isn't pointing to a valid place in memory to store a string

Comment: C uses the old style stack/heap memory management so you'll need to read up on how pointers and malloc work.

Comment: @ChrisTurner is correct, batch_cmds is a pointer to nothing, you need to manage the memory or statically allocate it, I would suggest using a linked list and allocate each node when you successfully read a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have reserved space for the pointers themselves, but not for each string to which each such pointer shall point to. Each `batch_cmds[i]` points "somewhere", at least not to an object you allocated; when you then call `strcpy(batch_cmds[i], str);`, you write the contents of `str` to "somewhere" and produce undefined behaviour (e.g. a crash; actually statement `batch_cmds[i]` accesses an uninitialized array and is for itself already undefined behaviour; yet this alone seldomly leads to a crash).

Instead of

```
strcpy(batch_cmds[i], str);
```

write

```
batch_cmds[i] = strdup(str);
```

Command `strdup` does both - (1) reserving memory large enough to hold the contents of `str` and (2) copying the contents of `str` then. This is equivalent to  `batch_cmds[i] = malloc(strlen(str)+1); strcpy(batch_cmds[i], str));`.

Additionally, check that `i` is `<512`, such that `batch_cmds[i]` will not exceed array bounds.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Couldn't explain it better. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
char *batch_cmds[512];
```

Declares an array of 512 pointers to `char`, but those pointers are uninitialized (wild, dangling, take your pick).

Your options:

1. Declare a 2D array on the stack:

   ```
   char batch_cmds[512][512];
   ```
2. Use dynamic memory management to allocate the strings on the heap:

   ```
   char *batch_cmds[512];
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 512; i++)
   {
       batch_cmds[i] = malloc(string_length);
       if(batch_cmds[i] == NULL)
       {
            // handle alloc error
       }
   }

   // Code that uses batch_cmds...

   for(i = 0; i < 512; i++)
   {
       free(batch_cmds[i]);
       batch_cmds[i] = NULL;
   }
   ```
3. Use `strdup` to assign to the pointers to `char` in `batch_cmds` (demonstrated in Stephan Lechner's answer). Note that `strdup` also uses heap memory behind the scenes so the returned pointers must also be passed to `free` when you're done with them to avoid memory leaks.